# Lookup for element in custom generic container (object transformation with lambdas) C++

Tags: c++, generics, lambda, functional-programming

I am building a generic class which will manage pointers of any type.

This is my class:

**GenericManager.h**

```
template <class T> class GenericManager {
    public:
        void add(T element) const;

        //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        template <class R>
        bool exists(const R& element, R(*fn)(const T& a)) const;

    private:
    List<T>* list = new ArrayList<T>(); //own implementation, has add, [], remove 
}
```

**exists method implementation**

```
bool GenericManager<T>::exists(const R& elem, R(*fn)(const T& a) {
   for(int i = 0; i < list->size(); i++) {
       T e = (*list)[i];
       if(fn(e) == elem) return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

I expect the exist method to check if list contains object with certain attribute. transform object T into R and compare with the one from parameter.

**Example:**

```
struct Vehicle {
    string licensePlate;
}

string lookFor("ABCD");
GenericManager<Vehicle*> manager;

Vehicle *v = new Vehicle();
v->licensePlate = lookFor;
manager.add(v);

//check if manager managers vehicle with 'lookFor' license plate
manager.exists(
                 lookFor, 
                 [](const Vehicle*& a) -> std::string { return a->licensePlate;}
              );
```

But it does not compiles due:

```
no instance of function template "GenericManager<T>::exists [with T=Vehicle *]" matches the argument list

argument types are: (std::string, lambda []std::string (const Vehicle*& c)->std::string)
object type is: GenericManager<Vehicle *>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the parameter passed to your lambda doesn't match the type of the parameter of the function pointer to exists. The following code works:

```
typedef Vehicle* pVehicle;
manager.exists(
                 lookFor, 
                 [](const pVehicle & a) -> std::string { return a->licensePlate;}
              );
```

The difference is between a const ref to a pointer (required by the function pointer) and a reference to a pointer to a const object (as declared in the lambda)

Comment: Thanks for the response. But it does not work either.